# .Net core app runs with EXE but does not run on IIS

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, iis, amazon-ec2

I have a .Net Core 6 app which runs fine locally, it also runs fine when I manually start the exe in the publish folder.

However when I run on IIS, it gives the following error.

[image]

The server is an AWS EC2 server, I have all ports open as a test as incoming on the firewall, I have also tried to disable the firewall completely and also allowing the app through the firewall. As far as I'm aware there is no AV on the EC2 instance.

I have added the .net core 6 runtime and I have also installed the .NET Core hosting bundle found here:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

When I have checked the event viewer logs I get this error message:

> Application: WebApi.exe
> CoreCLR Version: 6.0.222.6406
> .NET Version: 6.0.2
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://localhost:4000.
>
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.) (An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.)
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException (SocketError error, String callerName)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportOptions.CreateDefaultBoundListenSocket(EndPoint endpoint)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig endpointConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`1.<g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I have read there is a setting on old versions of .NetCore to specify the use of IIS, but I can't see one for .Net Core 6.

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out what is wrong.

Here is what is shown when I run the exe on it's own, which is correct.

[image]

Comment: Are you deploying self-contained? And do you have `hostingModel="inprocess"` in your config?

Comment: I am deploying as self contained yes, I also did have inprocess but this caused a different issue so I changed to OutOfProcess

Comment: Run this locally on IIS and if that doesn't work, not an issue with AWS.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me rule out EC2.  I have found the issue now I will post the answer

Comment: @user3284707 You are most welcome, try to keep the minimal setup to ensure your problem is as contained as possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have finally found the reason.

It was due to my program.cs file having this line at the bottom:

```cs
app.Run("http://localhost:4000");
```

I changed this to the following and changed the port to 5000 on IIS and it all started working

```cs
app.Run();
```